# gcloud init ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'quota_project_id'

Tags: homebrew, gcloud, homebrew-cask

When I run the `gcloud init` command and log into my Google user account I receive the error

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'quota_project_id'
```

I've installed google-cloud-sdk with homebrew cask:

```
brew cask install google-cloud-sdk
source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"
source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"
```

Installing with `install.sh` from [google-cloud-sdk-291.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos) and running the gcloud init command again solves the issue. Any idea why the homebrew version isn't working?

Installation information:

```
$ gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 291.0.0
bq 2.0.57
core 2020.05.01
gsutil 4.50
```

macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: I would suggest [creating an issue in Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so we may investigate this. Please share detailed reproduction steps and any details you may find relevant about your environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue with gcloud SDK `v298.0.0` recently.

Here is my error log

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I ended up locking down the gcloud SDK version to `297.0.1`.

```
gcloud --quiet components update --version 297.0.1
```